# How to use local * on reference arguments?

Tags: perl, scope

This question is related to the last point of Item 46 in *Effective Perl Programming*.

I tested out this function, which allows you to pass array references, but access them as local arrays:

```
use strict;
sub max_v_local {
    local ( *a, *b ) = @_;
    my $n = @a > @b ? @a : @b;
    my @result;
    for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < $n ; $i++ ) {
        push @result, $a[$i] > $b[$i] ? $a[$i] : $b[$i];
    }
    @result;
}
```

But I got the following errors unless I don't use `strict`:

```
Variable "@a" is not imported
Variable "@b" is not imported
Global symbol "@a" requires explicit package name
Global symbol "@b" requires explicit package name
```

Is there a way to do this with `strict`?

### Update

Some further background. The above subroutine was a refinement of what follows. The subroutine takes 2 arrayrefs, but using the arrayrefs in the subroutine can get messy. The above code will probably be faster and is more readable since it enables you to access the arrayrefs as local arrays.

```
sub max_v {
    my ( $a, $b ) = @_;
    my $n = @$a > @$b ? @$a : @$b; # no. of items
    my @result;
    for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < $n ; $i++ ) {
        push @result, $$a[$i] > $$b[$i] ? $$a[$i] : $$b[$i];
    }
    @result;
}
```

I haven't paid much attention to globs prior to this, so I'm having a look at them now. Turns out that they're not as complicated as I thought.

Comment: You do realize that this is an archaic construction in Perl, from the before time in the long long ago when there were no references and no lexical variables?

Comment: no I didn't realise that. Is it really? The book came out in 2010 though. I'll give more background to why I wanted to get this to work.

Comment: "can get messy":  No.  Trivially more characters, but hardly messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Declare them with [our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html):

```
use strict;
sub max_v_local {
    local ( *x, *y ) = @_;
    our (@x, @y);
    my $n = @x > @y ? @x : @y;
    my @result;
    for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < $n ; $i++ ) {
        push @result, $x[$i] > $y[$i] ? $x[$i] : $y[$i];
    }
    @result;
}
```

(It's generally not a good idea to use variables named `a` or `b` for anything except `sort`.)

Comment: yeah I noticed the issue with using `a` and `b`, but that is the code straight from the book. In fact, `a` and `b` are used throughout the entire book.

Answer (score 3):

As cjm mentions, you need to declare the variables with `our` (or use fully qualified names).

Now for a few tips.  First off, assigning from `@_` into a glob unchecked is a bit of a gamble.  I would write the line like this:

```
our (@a, @b);
local (*a, *b) = map \@$_ => @_;
```

That way, you have ensured that the only things passed to your subroutine are actually array references.  Perl will throw an error if the value is not an array reference.  You can of course write a verbose check if you want a more detailed message:

```
ref eq 'ARRAY' or die "..." for @_;
our (@a, @b);
local (*a, *b) = @_;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the package variables `@a` and `@b`, so you want to use [our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html). It's almost a per-variable `no strict "vars";`, and it's lexically scoped.

```
sub max_v_local {
    local ( *a, *b ) = @_;
    our ( @a, @b );
    ...
}
```

But there is a problem in your algorithm. You're comparing elements of the longer array to elements that don't exist. That will give warnings and give the wrong result for negative values. Fix:

```
sub max_v_local {
    local ( *a, *b ) = @_;
    our ( @a, @b );
    my $n = @a < @b ? @a : @b;
    return
       ( map { $a[$_] > $b[$_] ? $a[$_] : $b[$_] } 0..$n-1 ),
       @a[ @b .. $#a ],
       @b[ @a .. $#b ];
}
```

Also, it's odd to take references and return a list, though. You might want to return an array reference. (`return [ ... ];`)

Answer (score 0):

Think it might be because you haven't explicitly declared your variable @a and @b